# Unterschiede zwischen Brauch, Sitte, Ritual, Ritus, Tradition

Tags: meaning

Wo genau bestehen Unterschiede und Überschneidungen bezüglich dieser 5 Begriffe: *Brauch*, *Sitte*, *Ritual*, *Ritus*, *Tradition*?

Comment: Ich habe die genannten Begriffe gerade mal in der Wikipedia nachgeschlagen, Unterschiede und Gemeinsamkeiten ergeben sich vortrefflich aus den jeweiligen Artikeln, allerdings sind diese auch sehr umfangreich.

Comment: hmm, stimmt. Ich kann mir auch die Antwort aus den ganzen Wikipedia-Artikeln zusammensuchen. Soll ich die Frage hier wieder löschen?

Comment: Ich würde die Frage in Hoffnung auf eine kurze und bündige Antwort stehen lassen, denn auch viele Muttersprachler können diese Begriffe nicht klar voneinander abgrenzen.

Comment: Die Unterschiede sind gering, vage und werden wahrscheinlich häufig missachtet. Für eine gute Antwort sollte man also doch eher alle 5 Wikipedia-Artikel lesen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mit Definitionen wird man da nicht viel weiter kommen. Wenn ich von Bayern oder sonstigen Regionen Deutschlands rede, würde ich Brauch  verwenden, wenn das mehr auf ein begrenzetes Gebiet beschränkt ist - Das ist Brauch in Tegernsee - oder von Sitte, wenn es mehr allgemeiner  Natur ist - Das ist Sitte in Deutschland.

Von Ritual würde ich bei anderen, exotischen Völkern sprechen - das Harakiri-Ritual der Samurai in Japan.
Von Ritus würde ich im Bereich der Kirche sprechen.

Das lateinische Wort Tradition vermittelt die Vorstellung, dass etwas über Gernerationen und Jahrhunderte weitergegeben wurde und wird - von lat. tra-dere weitergeben.

Das würde ich so aus dem Handgelenk heraus erklären. Weitere Analysen halte ich für Spitzfindigkeiten, die aber für den praktischen Gebrauch kaum Wert haben.

Comment: Die Frage kam von einem 12jährigen Kind. Dafür ist die Antwort perfekt. GefälltMir++

Comment: Oh, danke, falkb. Wußte nicht, dass die Frage von einem Kind gestellt wurde. Aber ich versuche immer, die Dinge so einfach wie möglich zu machen. Halte nichts von akademischem Kauderwelsch.

Answer (score 3):

Brauch: gefestigte Gewohnheit einer Gemeinschaft
Tradition (lateinisch) = Brauch (germanisch)
Sitte: 'moralische' Norm innerhalb einer Gemeinschaft
Ritus: religiöser Brauch
Ritual: festgelegter Ablauf einer religiösen Handlung